# Image Magick blur part of image with mask

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I'm trying to blur the lower part of an image and repeat this for several hundred other images within a target folder. I'm using this command:

```
magick 1.jpg -write-mask mask.png -blur 0x60 +write-mask 2.jpg
```

This does the the blurring but it takes between 10 - 20 seconds for one 5888 × 2944 image.

Is there someway to speed up this above command or is there a better command which will quickly batch blur a group of images?

Thanks!

Comment: Blur the whole image by using resize down then blur with a small sigma, then -resize up. Then use the mask to blend between the original and the blurred image. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tidbits/image.php#fast_gblur

Comment: I'm really quite new to imagemagick so I'm not very familiar with the commands. I sort of understand the method but I don't know how to create the command for this, if possible would you be able to help me create a simple command I can run to test? I would be really grateful! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you can blur a region by blurring the whole image, then blend that with the original using mask.  You can speed up a large blur by resizing (scaling) the image down, use a smaller blur and then resizing back up.

Input:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Slow:

```
time magick barns_grand_tetons.jpg \
\( +clone -blur 0x60 \) \
barns_grand_tetons_mask.png \
-compose over -composite slow_blur.jpg
4.521s
```

[image]

Fast:

```
time magick barns_grand_tetons.jpg \
-set option:dims "%wx%h" \
\( +clone -scale 10% -blur 0x6 -scale "%[dims]" \) \
barns_grand_tetons_mask.png \
-compose over -composite fast_blur.jpg
0.368s
```

[image]

See

https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#write_mask

**ADDITION**

If you want to feather the edges, you need to blur the mask as well.

Slow:

```
time magick barns_grand_tetons.jpg \
\( +clone -blur 0x60 \) \
\( barns_grand_tetons_mask.png -blur 0x10 -level 0x50% \) \
-compose over -composite slow_blur.jpg
 5.183s
```

[image]

Fast:

```
time magick barns_grand_tetons.jpg \
-set option:dims "%wx%h" \
\( +clone -scale 10% -blur 0x6 -scale "%[dims]" \) \
\( barns_grand_tetons_mask.png -scale 20% -blur 0x2 -level 0x50% -scale "%[dims]" \) \
-compose over -composite fast_blur.jpg
0.404s
```

[image]

If you want to feather outside the mask rather than inside the mask (as above), then change -level 0x50% to -level 50x100%.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to add a "feathered" edge to the blurred section's edge? So that it appears more natural?

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the new answer! I tried slightly modifying your command to be able to add blur to all images within a folder, replacing the input image name with 'time magick *.jpg \' and the output image name with '-compose over -composite "%[filename:base].jpg"' but this only seems to blur the first image. How can I blur all photos and overwrite their file names within a folder?

Comment: You cannot have wild cards for the input and auto-name the output for each. You will need to write a script loop over each file in the folder to do that.